# Funny games for 1 player with chess theme

Tags: chess-variants

I'm looking for some ideas on good games for one player (to create) that would be enjoyable, fun and with at least a little chess logic.

I already created one that I very like. Searching for pairs of white and black piece of same value in symetric material positions **from real games** (P:P, B:B, N:N, R:R, Q:Q, K:K). Looks like the picture. One must be very careful to reveal all pairs without single error, pawns help a lot but by far not easy. Understanding pawn structures, typical openings very helps here so this is the chess part for this game.

[image]

Similarly I made also one where you are looking for pawns knowing count of pawns and knowing where pieces stand. Clicking empty square is error obviously in this game. Not bad but the first is better :)

Any ideas for not very hard games that would be funny on touch screen devices are welcome. Preferably games that will be funny to play repeatedly. It is no problem to search for whatever type of positions necessary in game database, but I don't like creating random positions that aren't real as the chess value of such games would probably be very low...

Edit: Does not neceassarily have to be logical but can be memory game or ever some quiz or game for fast decison making.

Answer (score 3):

1. find the most/least attacked square (or some other special square) on the board quickly
2. arranging pieces on the board with a certain condition (this can be the classic 8 queens problem, but also other pieces with other condition); perhaps not realistic enough for you, though IMO this can teach you a lot about how the pieces move
3. guess the opening based on some position
4. guess the move in a famous game; perhaps too close to chess for your purpose
5. some retrograde problems

Answer (score 0):

Ubisoft's *Chessmaster* program had a few fun games:

- **Fork my fruit**:

> move pieces to a square so that they can fork whatever fruit is in their line of movement.

Quote source: [ign](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2008/02/28/chessmaster-the-art-of-learning-review)

- **Minesweeper**:

A game where you diffuse hidden mines by not running over them and diffusing them, similar to capturing.

- **Snake**:

> where the player chooses a long-range chess piece, then trying to make a long tail using captured pieces, and avoiding the enemy pieces to capture the main piece or tail parts.

Quote source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessmaster)